# Self implemented templatized Vector and BST. 1

Tags: c++

```
    #ifndef VECTOR_H
    #define VECTOR_H

    /**
    * A minimal vector that can dynamically store multiple objects
    */
    template <class T>
    class Vector
    {
    public:
        /**
        * Create an initial vector
        */
        Vector();

        /**
        * Delete memory allocated resources
        */
        ~Vector();

        /**
        * Copy constructor
        */
        Vector(const Vector& other);

        /**
         * Assignment operator
         * \param other Object to assign from
         * \return A reference to this
         */
        Vector& operator=(const Vector& other);

        /**
        * Add a new element at the end of the list
        * @param element item to be added
        */
        void push_back(T element);

        /**
        * Return the number of items stored in the vector
        * @return size
        */
        int size();

        /**
        * Get an element from a specific index
        * @param i index
        * @return element
        */
        T get(int i);

        /**
        * Check if the element is in the list
        * @return true if it is, otherwise false
        */
        bool contains(T element);

    private:

        /**
        * Stores the current number of elements
        */
        unsigned int numElements;

        /**
        * Stores the maximum number of elements that can be stored
        */
        unsigned int capacity;

        /**
        * A dynamically allocated list where to store items
        */
        T *elements;

        /**
        * Doubles the size of the vector
        */
        void expand();
    };

    template <class T>
    Vector<T>::Vector()
    {
        numElements = 0;
        capacity = 10;
        elements = new T[capacity];
    }

    template <class T>
    Vector<T>::~Vector()
    {
        delete[] elements;
    }

    template <class T>
    void Vector<T>::push_back(T element)
    {
        if (numElements >= capacity)
        {
            expand();
        }

        elements[numElements] = element;
        numElements++;
    }

    template <class T>
    int Vector<T>::size()
    {
        return numElements;
    }

    template <class T>
    T Vector<T>::get(int i)
    {
        return elements[i];
    }

    template <class T>
    void Vector<T>::expand()
    {
        T *tempElements = new T[capacity * 2];

        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        {
            tempElements[i] = elements[i];
        }

        delete[] elements;
        elements = tempElements;
        capacity *= 2;
    }

    template <class T>
    bool Vector<T>::contains(T element)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < numElements; i++)
        {
            if (elements[i] == element)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    #endif
```

Please give me any comments you can, one doubt I have in particular is do I leave the parameters that take T element as is, or should it be T *element or T &element, it's a very confusing topic for me.

And also, how would one privatize a struct that is defined outside the class, rather than posting more unreadable code, since I don't want the client to edit the root/node values himself.

```
    /**
    @class BinarySearchTree.h
    @brief is class which deals with the BST insertion, deletion, searching, getting, etc

    @author Aashish Pandav
    @date 27/7/2016

    */

    #ifndef BINARYSEARCHTREE_H
    #define BINARYSEARCHTREE_H

    /**
    * A node to link together and form a binary search tree
    */
    template <class T>
    struct Node
    {
        T element;
        Node<T> *left;
        Node<T> *right;
    };

    /**
    * A binary search tree to store elements in sorted order
    */
    template <class T>
    class BinarySearchTree
    {
    public:
        /**
        * Create an empty binary search tree
        */
        BinarySearchTree();

        /**
        * Delete all memory allocated objects
        */
        ~BinarySearchTree();

        /**
        * Insert a new element in the binary search tree
        * @param element New element to be inserted
        */
        void insert(T element);

        /**
        * Check if the element is in the tree
        * @param element Target element
        * @return true if it is, otherwise false
        */
        bool contains(T element);

        /**
        * Get an item from a particular index
        * @param index target index
        * @return element
        */
        T get(int index);

        /**
        * Get the number of items stored in the binary tree
        * @return size
        */
        int size();
    private:
        /**
        * Holds the root reference
        */
        Node<T> *root;

        /**
        * Recursively delete a binary search tree
        * @param current current element to destroy
        */
        void destroy(Node<T>* &current);

        /**
        * Recursively count the number of items stored
        * @param current current node being counted
        * @return number of elements
        */
        int size(Node<T> *current);
    };

    template <class T>
    BinarySearchTree<T>::BinarySearchTree()
    {
        root = NULL;
    }

    template <class T>
    BinarySearchTree<T>::~BinarySearchTree()
    {
        destroy(root);
    }

    template <class T>
    int BinarySearchTree<T>::size()
    {
        return size(root);
    }

    template <class T>
    int BinarySearchTree<T>::size(Node<T> *current)
    {
        if (current == NULL)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        return 1 + size(current->left) + size(current->right);
    }

    template <class T>
    T BinarySearchTree<T>::get(int index)
    {
        Node<T> *node = root;
        int position = size(root->left);

        while (position != index)
        {
            if (index > position)
            {
                node = node->right;
                position = position + 1 + size(node->left);
            }
            else
            {
                node = node->left;
                position = position - 1 - size(node->right);
            }
        }

        return node->element;
    }

    template <class T>
    void BinarySearchTree<T>::destroy(Node<T>* &current)
    {
        if (current != NULL)
        {
            destroy(current->left);
            destroy(current->right);
            delete current;
            current = NULL;
        }
    }

    template <class T>
    void BinarySearchTree<T>::insert(T element)
    {
        Node<T> *newNode = new Node<T>();
        newNode->element = element;
        newNode->left = NULL;
        newNode->right = NULL;

        if (root == NULL)
        {
            root = newNode;
        }
        else
        {
            Node<T> *previous = NULL;
            Node<T> *current = root;

            while (current != NULL)
            {
                previous = current;

                if (current->element == element)
                {
                    // Duplicate
                    delete newNode;
                    return;
                }
                else if (current->element > element)
                {
                    current = current->left;
                }
                else if (current->element < element)
                {
                    current = current->right;
                }
            }

            if (previous->element > element)
            {
                previous->left = newNode;
            }
            else if (previous->element < element)
            {
                previous->right = newNode;
            }
        }
    }

    template <class T>
    bool BinarySearchTree<T>::contains(T element)
    {
        Node<T> *current = root;

        while (current != NULL)
        {
            if (current->element == element)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else if (element > current->element)
            {
                current = current->right;
            }
            else if (element < current->element)
            {
                current = current->left;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    #endif
```

Comment: Welcome to code review, a very similar question was just asked, you might want to look at the answer. http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/160171/another-vector-implementation-looking-for-feedback-on-an-implementation-follow

Answer (score 2):

### Design

Your storage requires that `T` has a default constructor.

```
T *elements;

// Allocation is 
elements = new T[capacity];   // Creates `capacity` elements 
                              // But also constructs them.
```

There are a couple of problems with this.

1. Your type `T` needs a default constructor.
2. If the constructor is expensive then you are constructing a bunch of object temporally that you may never use.

What you want to do is allocate enough memory to store `capacity` objects to be created but not actually create them until you need them. For this you will need to understand `Placement new`.

### Rule of three

You declare the copy constructor and copy assignment operator but I don't see a definition. So it is hard to tell if they work.

### Pass by reference.

```
void Vector<T>::push_back(T element)
```

Here you pass `element` by value. This means you copy the value into the parameter. Then you copy the value into the storage element (using copy assignment).

What you need to do is pass by reference:

```
void Vector<T>::push_back(T const& element)
                      //    ^^^^^^
```

This prevents one copy.
You may also want to add a move assignment operator.

```
void Vector<T>::push_back(T&& element) noexcept;
```

### Const Correctness

Any method that does not change the state of the object should be marked `const`. This allows the method to be called from a const context (ie when passed as a parameter as a const reference).

```
int Vector<T>::size() const
                  //  ^^^^^ add const here.
```

### Return by reference

```
T Vector<T>::get(int i)
```

Here you are returning by value. Which means that the returned value is copied out of the object. What you should do is return a reference to the object

```
T& Vector<T>::get(int i);
 ^^  Return a reference. This allows you to read the value.
     But also modify the object in place.
```

Note: This will not work in a `const` context. So you should also have a version where you can read a value (ie it does not allow modification). This version can be used in `const` context.

```
T const& Vector<T>::get(int i) const;
                           //  ^^^^^ This function does not modify the state of the objet.
//^^^^^^                             We return a const reference to the object.
//                                   This allows you to read it but not modify it.
```

### Stop using `NULL`

```
    root = NULL;
```

C++ has a better literal. `nullptr` is the literal that represents a `null`.

### More Info

[Vector - Resource Management Allocation](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/02/27/vector/)
[Vector - Resource Management Copy Swap](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/02/29/vector-resource-management-ii-copy-assignment/)
[Vector - Resize](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/03/12/vector-resize/)
[Vector - Simple Optimizations](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/03/19/vector-simple-optimizations/)
[Vector - the Other Stuff](http://lokiastari.com/blog/2016/03/20/vector-the-other-stuff/)